# Primefaces DataExporter - Arabic letters are being displayed disjointed and above each other

Tags: pdf, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-dataexporter

I have added a DataExporter. If the data grid has Arabic letters, they are not being deployed at all, or they are being displayed disjoint and above each other. Here is an image:

[image]

To solve the issue, I have added PDFOption, including a new `Arial` font.

```
    pdfOpt = new PDFOptions();
    InputStream fontStream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/fonts/arial.ttf");
    BaseFont baseFont = null;
    try {
        baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, fontStream.readAllBytes(), null);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PrimefacesPDFExporterOptions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PrimefacesPDFExporterOptions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Font font = new Font(baseFont, 12, Font.NORMAL);
    pdfOpt.setFontName(font.getBaseFont().getFullFontName()[0][3]);
```

The problem with this solution is that I am not being able to set the font it self, just the name of it. So, I need to set the encoding. To do that, I added encoding attribute to the `p:dataExporter` and set the value to `Identity-H`:

```
<p:dataExporter options="#{primefacesPDFExporterOptions.pdfOpt}" encoding="Identity-H" type="pdf" preProcessor="#{primefacesPDFExporterOptions.makePDFLandscape}" pageOnly="false" target="explorerResultsTableId" fileName="data"/>
```

This did not solve the issue!

Another option I am trying to apply, is to change the font of every cell in the PDF to the created one. But I am not able to get the cells!

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic solution for `PF 12`, to get the work done, with few changes, but can be improved. I define a custom `exporter` in the `xhtml`, like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="PDF">
    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="cars" fileName="cars" exporter="#{dataGridView.exporter}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

I use a font compatible with Arabic characters, like `ARIALUNI.TTF` and I embedded the file in the project (it's easily findable on the internet).
I initialized the `exporter` on class creation:

```
public class DataGridView implements Serializable {
    ...
        
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       ...
       exporter = new MyPDFExporter();
    }
    ...
}
```

`MyPDFExporter` is most likely PF version (`DataTableExporter`), I only change the `applyFont` function, to use the embedded one (I can't get it working directly, passing by option), so it looks like this

```
protected void applyFont(String fontName, String encoding) {
    InputStream fontStream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF");
    BaseFont baseFont = null;
    try {
        baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, fontStream.readAllBytes(), null);
    } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
    }
    cellFont = new Font(baseFont);
    facetFont = new Font(baseFont);
}
```

The only change with `PF 12` default version is the use of a font compatible with Unicode characters.
AFAIK the older `PF` version doesn't use `openpdf` so you need `pdfCalligraph` to get it works with `itext`.
Some useful related questions:

- [How to display Arabic in PDF created using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357181/how-to-display-arabic-in-pdf-created-using-itext)
- [Writing Arabic in pdf using itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726908/writing-arabic-in-pdf-using-itext)
- [How can I use the primefaces DataExporter to export PDFs with Arabic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548234/how-can-i-use-the-primefaces-dataexporter-to-export-pdfs-with-arabic-data)